# Include Django template without newline

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

My `main.html` template contains the following code:

```
<p>{% include "pouac.html" %}{% include "pouac.html" %}</p>
```

The `pouac.html` file contains a single line:

```
<span>pouac</span>
```

The `main.html` template produces the following **two** lines of html code:

```
<span>pouac</span>
<span>pouac</span>
```

The nasty side effect is that this code produces some white space between the two "pouac" words (e.g: "word1" and "word2" are separated by a whitespace in http://jsfiddle.net/regisb/CBtaz/)

In order to get rid of this whitespace, I would like to render a Django template without adding an extranuous line break. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the spaceless [1] template tag.

```
{% spaceless %}{% include "pouac.html" %}{% include "pouac.html" %}{% endspaceless %}
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

Answer (score 6):

You may want to wrap it in Django's built-in [`spaceless'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) template tag:

```
<p>{% spaceless %}{% include "pouac.html" %}{% include "pouac.html" %}{% endspaceless %}</p>
```